# Does anyone know of fan made subtitles for 'The Last Story' (Wii)?

Tags: the-last-story

I've been really looking forward to this game and am pretty much going to import the Japanese version no matter what. I was wondering if anyone has knowledge of fan made subtitles for the game. I've heard of this happening with other titles before and wondered if this would be the case here, especially as so many like me were looking forward to this title.

If there are fan subtitles in the works I'd imagine they would be quite small and hard to find, atleast at first.

If anyone knows of fan subtitles, even if they are still work in progress, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing over the last several days since my copy arrived. Unfortunately, there is none available yet. However there is a translation-wiki in the build, just google "Last Story Translation".

It is my belief that it will take another month or so to get someone to decide he (or she) is going to translate the game and/or create a patch. That would then make for another two weeks or so to get around the technical issues of locating the strings inside the DVD-image and (obviously) an unestimatable amount of time to actually translate it.

Personally, I'm quite a bit into the game currently and apart from understanding the story I'm actually able to play it. The interface is in english for the most part. And a katakana-chart helps to translate item-names quickly.